# Locating specific data in a multi-index data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I created a dataframe using this code...

```
robotdata = np.array([ [ 0.26 , 0.92 , 0.05 , 0.43 ] ,
                       [ 1.00 , 0.62 , 1.00 , 1.00 ] , 
                       [ 1.00 , 0.97 , 0.04 , 1.00 ] ,
                       [ 0.00 , 1.00 , 1.00 , 0.88 ] ,
                       [ 1.00 , 1.00 , 1.00 , 0.79 ] ,
                       [ 0.98 , 1.00 , 0.79 , 0.99 ] ,
                       [ 0.99 , 1.00 , 1.00 , 1.00 ] ,
                       [ 0.18 , 1.00 , 0.26 , 1.00 ] ,
                       [ 0.22 , 0.00 , 0.34 , 0.82 ] ])

robotrowIndx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product ([[ 'Slurm' , 'Zoidberg' , 'Wernstrom' ] , 
                                              [ 'A' , 'B' , 'C' ]] , 
                                             names =[ 'Laboratory' , 'Device' ])

robotcolIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product ([[ 'Replicant 1' , 'Replicant 2' ] , 
                                             [ 'Silicon' , 'Carbon' ]] , 
                                            names = [ 'Replicant' , 'Element' ])

robot = pd.DataFrame ( data = robotdata , index = robotrowIndx , columns = robotcolIndex )

robot
```

Now I need to Create a new object 'R1CC' that corresponds to the results of Device C using Carbon for Replicant 1.

I've tried something like this, but was unsuccessful...

```
R1CC = robot.loc ['C' , ('Carbon' & 'Replicant 1')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html#pandas-indexslice):

```
indx = pd.IndexSlice
r1cc = robot.loc[indx[:,'C'], indx['Replicant 1','Carbon']]
```

Output:

```
Laboratory  Device
Slurm       C         0.97
Zoidberg    C         1.00
Wernstrom   C         0.00
Name: (Replicant 1, Carbon), dtype: float64
```

Comment: Would this work in reverse?  Like If I wanted to find results of A and B based on Carbon, would it just be...

`
robot.loc [ indx['A','B'], indx[:,'Carbon'] ]
`

Comment: `xs` also works.  `robot['Replicant 1'].Carbon.xs('C', level=1)`.  In general, I'd use `xs` to target specific single values in one or more levels. `robot.xs(['Slurm', 'C'])`  And use `pd.IndexSlice` when I want more than one value in a particular level `robot.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ['A', 'C']], :]`

Comment: Not sure if I helped or just made things more confusing >.<